# Some problems in jquery variable

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I don't know how to put the value from a PHP variable into a jQuery variable. I tried some ways but still it doesnt work.

```
checkboxstatus = "<?php echo $checkboxstatus; ?>";
```

Everytime when I do this in database the row looks like:

[image]

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#wyslij").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkboxstatus = "<?php echo $checkboxstatus; ?>";

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "czekboks.php",
      data: {
        checkboxstatus: checkboxstatus
      },
      success: function(result) {
        console.log('the data was successfully sent to the server');
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: For that to work you need to execute your jQuery/JS code in a PHP page, not a JS page, which is part of the reason it's not a good pattern to follow. A better idea would be to set the `$checkboxstatus` value as a data attribute on the `#wyslij` element and read that back in the click event without the need for any PHP spaghetti.

Comment: I recommend looking up what the difference between client-side and server-side coding is.

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan. :)

Comment: you can't use php inside JS. You can do it the other way around tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can localize the PHP variable and then use it in the js file.